# Can someone please verify my new 10-monitor.conf set up? 12.04

Tags: 12.04, xorg, multiple-monitors, intel-graphics

I'm working on getting X to recognize my DisplayLink Adapter. I have an onboard Intel HD 3000 chipset.

Here is the uldfb:

```
lloydm@lloydm-E6320:~$ dmesg | grep -i udlfb
[20006.928772] udlfb: DisplayLink IOGEAR External DVI - serial #112644
[20006.928780] udlfb: vid_17e9&pid_0059&rev_0102 driver's dlfb_data struct at ffff880157ec4000
[20006.928781] udlfb: console enable=1
[20006.928782] udlfb: fb_defio enable=1
[20006.928783] udlfb: shadow enable=1
[20006.928882] udlfb: vendor descriptor length:22 data:22 5f 01 0020 05 00 01 03 04 02
[20006.928884] udlfb: DL chip limited to 2080000 pixel modes
[20006.928940] udlfb: allocated 4 65024 byte urbs
[20006.929002] usbcore: registered new interface driver udlfb
[20007.023505] udlfb: 1920x1200 beyond chip capabilities
[20007.023515] udlfb: 720x400 @ 70 Hz valid mode
[20007.023521] udlfb: 640x480 @ 60 Hz valid mode
[20007.023524] udlfb: 640x480 @ 75 Hz valid mode
[20007.023528] udlfb: 800x600 @ 60 Hz valid mode
[20007.023531] udlfb: 800x600 @ 75 Hz valid mode
[20007.023535] udlfb: 1024x768 @ 60 Hz valid mode
[20007.023539] udlfb: 1024x768 @ 75 Hz valid mode
[20007.023543] udlfb: 1280x1024 @ 75 Hz valid mode
[20007.023546] udlfb: 1280x1024 @ 60 Hz valid mode
[20007.023550] udlfb: 1600x1200 @ 60 Hz valid mode
[20007.023553] udlfb: 1920x1200 beyond chip capabilities
[20007.023556] udlfb: 1152x864 @ 75 Hz valid mode
[20007.023561] udlfb: Reallocating framebuffer. Addresses will change!
[20007.025615] udlfb: 1600x1200 @ 60 Hz valid mode
[20007.025619] udlfb: set_par mode 1600x1200
[20007.035253] udlfb: DisplayLink USB device /dev/fb1 attached. 1600x1200 resolution. Using 7504K framebuffer memory
[35424.954154] udlfb: open /dev/fb1 user=1 fb_info=ffff880157ec2000 count=1
[35427.104763] udlfb: released /dev/fb1 user=1 count=0
```

This was successful:

```
sudo dd if=test.png of=/dev/fb1
7500+1 records in
7500+1 records out
3840024 bytes (3.8 MB) copied, 0.260879 s, 14.7 MB/s
```

A little misaligned (1/4" wraparound to the right), but it was successful.

This is my current xrandr config:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3840 x 1200, maximum 32767 x 32767
LVDS1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1366x768       60.0 +   40.0  
   1360x768       59.8     60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
VGA1 connected primary 1920x1200+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 518mm x 324mm
   1920x1200      60.0*+
   1600x1200      60.0  
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1024x768       75.1     60.0  
   800x600        75.0     60.3  
   640x480        75.0     60.0  
   720x400        70.1  
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI3 connected 1920x1200+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 518mm x 324mm
   1920x1200      60.0*+
   1600x1200      60.0  
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1024x768       75.1     60.0  
   800x600        75.0     60.3  
   640x480        75.0     60.0  
   720x400        70.1  
DP2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Here is my proposed 10-monitor.conf configuration file (not applied yet):

```
Section "Device"
Identifier      "intel"
driver          "intel"
EndSection

Section "Device"
Identifier      "dl1"
driver          "displaylink"
Option  "fbdev" "/dev/fb1"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
Identifier "monitor0"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
Identifier "monitor1"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
Identifier "monitor2"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
Identifier "screen0"
Device "dl1"
Monitor "monitor0"
DefaultDepth 16
EndSection

Section "Screen"
Identifier "screen1"
Device "intel"
Monitor "monitor1"
DefaultDepth 16
EndSection

Section "Screen"
Identifier "screen2"
Device "intel"
Monitor "monitor2"
DefaultDepth 16
EndSection

Section "ServerLayout"
Identifier     "multihead"
Screen      0  "screen0" 1280 0
Screen      1  "screen1" RightOf "screen0"
Screen      2  "screen2" RightOf "screen1"
Option    "Xinerama" "on"
EndSection
```

I had to build it by hand. I'm not a super linux god yet. I have three monitors, two are working by default. I would like for someone who knows X way better than me to take a look at it before I apply it because I really don't feel like breaking my box. Again. Is this a right configuration?

Comment: Please explain how you want these to be set up. As one large desktop? Separate X instances on each screen? Also, the easiest way to test is to simply try this. If it doesn't work, you'll be taken to a tty, you can log in, delete/rename the file and reboot and you're back to normal.

Comment: True. I'd like it to be one large display. I know that's also not necessarily an option, and then I'll disable Xinema. I mostly just want to make sure that the formatting looks correct based on the info provided. I'm not good with Linux drivers yet so I just wanted a sanity check mostly.

Comment: I would suggest generating an X configuration to find out what your monitor likes in terms of xorg. You can do this by booting into recovery and running `X -configure` and then moving that file someone you can find it. Also, if your current configuration is usable, just saved it with .backup and then restore it if your  new one breaks.